# Is it possible to create/fork a Windows process with more than one network credential?

Tags: winapi, networking, networkcredentials

I know that, if I want to authenticate to network resources using a different credential, I can use the Win32 API to create processes with different network credentials, by passing `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` to calls like `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW`.

This is the equivalent of using the command-line `RUNAS /NETONLY ...`.

However, there is an edge case where the invoked process might need to access the network resource on the remote domain, and then access network resources within the end-user's own domain.

If I had full control of the invoked process, I expect I could fork it twice -- once with the user's regular credential and once with the network credential -- and use some sort of IPC to communicate between the processes.

Unfortunately, the invoked process is not in my control.

So, before I go too far down this rabbit hole, is there a Win32 API within that can create processes with multiple network credentials, that each apply to a specific target server?

Or do I have to take this edge case off the table, and push for replacing the invoked process?

Comment: The user account you use is under your control.  Simply use one that has access to both.

Comment: Can't.  No trust between the domains, and no common attributes between the accounts.  Access to the end-user's domain must be with the end-user's account, and access to the remote domain must be with the credentials supplied by that domains owner.

Comment: That requires impersonation, only the process itself can take care of that.  Does not beat the simple solution by a hundred miles, let the user account be known on the domain.

Comment: Agreed, but this is more a case where the politics are influencing the design.  The `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` approach is dealing with 99% of the problem -- it's just whether I have to say no to the remaining 1%, or if there is something in the API that I've missed...